# SO review section "Help and Improvement" has bug

Tags: bug, review-queues, help-improvement

I have faced a issue at the time of review in the section **Help and Improvement**. In this section, there comes two buttons **Edit** and **Skip**.

**ISSUE:**

After editing a post, I always see EDIT button. You can see in the picture:

[image]

*The correct scenario is, in the place of Edit button, after edit, there should come **Next** Button*.

**Reason:**

```
I have completed my all 20 reviews for this day.
```

**Fixed this issue as per:**

There should come a message of completed all reviews of days, come back after */hours.

Please fix this issue.

Comment: This isn't a bug. You're still encouraged to edit the same post as many times as it takes to get it right, and it won't count as a new review or do anything more to affect the queue entries. So while it would be *nice* to get the "20/day completed, come back in 43 seconds" message, that's really the only thing missing. The rest is exactly as expected.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have tried 3 times editing it. and after that I have reached to review section where I am seeing that I have completed my all 20 review for this section. That's why I am saying that it is a bug.

Comment: OK, but that's not in the main bug report here at all. Can you amend that?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Are you talking about tag bug-report? If yes then I will remove this tag.

Comment: That too, but I meant that that comment was the first time that behavior was described at all, and the described behavior in the question is still not buggy.

Comment: I agree that this behavior is unexpected and confusing. It wasn't clear to me that the Next button was gone because I had reached 20 reviews. A grayed out Next button with a tooltip or just an explanatory message would be nice.